# Is there some sort of pot with a sort of sieve on the bottom to separate sauce?

Tags: pot

I'm not a native English speaker so I'll do my best to explain what I envision.

I was wondering if there is some sort of... kitchen utensil, a pot of some kind that has a... sieve of some sort at its bottom to separate the food I'm trying to cook from the juices it extrudes?

So, say I'm putting some peas and corn in this thing and sprinkling them with grated cheese on top. Putting it in the oven when heating the cheese will start to ooze fat which kind of grosses me out, skip the judgement, I like the way I am, so it'd be perfect if there was this sieve thing at the bottom to let the fat through but keep the peas and corn on top.

Anyone know of such a thing or two separate utensils that are designed to be combined in such a way?

Comment: Hi, and welcome. We have quite a strict moderation here, and our code of conduct means that we delete posts which judge you for your preferences. I hope you will get working suggestions - the first one already looks promising.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Broiler pan.**

[image: broiler pan]

This is mine.  The last thing I made on it was bacon this past weekend.  It worked just like what you want - the bacon cooked and the fat dribbled down thru those slots into the pan below.

I have melted cheese many times on this pan.  It is perfect for nachos.

The other nice thing about melting cheese under the broiler is that you can get it really hot, fast.  The cheese melts some but gets toasty too which is the best of all.

I am too much of a provincial to know if other countries incorporate broilers in their ovens.  In US ovens the broiler is a heating element or heatable screen on the top of the inside of the oven.  Stuff to be cooked is placed underneath.

I always sit on the floor next to the oven when I am using the broiler because I am easily distracted and stuff burns in a heartbeat.  I was taught to leave the oven door open a crack when using the broiler.

---

Not sure why there is so much white space under the photo of the broiler pan.  That is not how the photo looks.  Ideas?  Edits?

Comment: idk, I don't see any excess white space below the photo? Also, thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

A steaming basket comes to mind.  These fit in a variety of pots and pans and keep items off the bottom.

[image]

Comment: That certainly seems like a very good idea. But it's more of a workaround. I was wondering if there isn't a tool/utensil/pot that was created with what I want in mind, specifically.